How to configure Azure pipeline approval check to deploy to Azure function apps?
We have 2 pipelines to deploy to our Azure function apps. One for dev and one for prod. The one for dev triggers automatically and doesn't require any approval. But the one for Prod triggers manually and requires approval check. Both pipelines are using a same service connection. Not sure how can I configure the approval check because when I go to the Environment I can only add 'Kubernetes' and 'Virtual Machines' as a resource.
trigger: 
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - function-app/**

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: aomdevops
      type: git
      name: AOM-Core/AOM-Devops

variables:
  - name: postmanEnv
    value: "postman/telco_local.postman_environment.json"

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    jobs:
      - job: DeployExtractInfo
        displayName: "Deploy Extract Info"
        steps:
          - template: templates/funcapp-deployment.yaml
            parameters:
              faName: 'funcapp-xxxxxxxxx'
              resourceGroup: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
              azureSvcConn: 'aom-azure'
              funcAppFolder: 'function-app/xxxxxxxxxxx/'
              funcAppName: 'exInfo'

      - job: DeployErrorHandling
        displayName: "Deploy Error Handling"
        steps:
          - template: templates/funcapp-deployment.yaml
            parameters:
              faName: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
              resourceGroup: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
              azureSvcConn: 'aom-azure'
              funcAppFolder: 'function-app/xxxxxxxxxx/'
              funcAppName: 'errHandling'


This question is similar to: How to add a manual intervention step in Azure Pipelines yaml. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The Environments i used as the target of deployments on the deployment type job. See "jobs.deployment definition" and "jobs.deployment.environment definition".
jobs:
- deployment: deploy
  environment: environmentName.resourceName
  . . .

Currently, the supported resource types (resourceType) in Environments are only virtualMachine and Kubernetes. Azure Function App is not supported.
For your case, you can use the ManualValidation@0 task to set up manual approvals in your YAML pipeline like as below.
# azure-pipelines.yml

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: approval
    displayName: 'Wait for Approval'
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          user1@example.com
          user2@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate and approve this deployment.'
        onTimeout: 'reject'
  
  - job: DeployExtractInfo
    displayName: 'Deploy Extract Info'
    dependsOn: approval
    . . .

  - job: DeployErrorHandling
    displayName: 'Deploy Error Handling'
    dependsOn: approval
    . . .

With this method, when to run the Deploy stage, it will first to run the approval job to wait for the specified users to approve. Once approved, it will start to run the subsequent DeployExtractInfo and DeployErrorHandling jobs.


Thanks @Bright Ran, the pipeline itself is working fine in your way but for some reason it doesn't send an email to the approvers to notify them. should i configure any other things for that?

@P.T, Have the users been added into the Azure DevOps organization and the project where the pipeline is running? Also check if the email addresses are correct.

Ran, yes, i have added myself to test but didn't receive any email

@P.T, Check the "Junk Email" list in you email-box to see if the notification message is there.

Ran, yes, it was there. Thank you :)
